# Make an S3 Bucket Permissions Public Access to 'Everyone' using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-sdk

How would I set the S3 Bucket Permissions for Public Access to 'Everyone' for Read Files using AWS CLI?

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html) does not have clear specification of how to do this and have tried multiple variations. My end goal is to make the bucket a static site server bucket.

Answer (score 3):

S3 Bucket ACL permission are set after the bucket is created - I achieved a public file read bucket using this command

`aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket ${SITE_NAME} --acl public-read`

After creating the bucket:

`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${SITE_NAME} --region ap-southeast-2 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=ap-southeast-2`

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below command will help you to make the s3 object public through the AWS CLI command.

`aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket <bucketname> --key <object name with extension> --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers`